# What analysis should I use to compare two groups on count data, non-independent observations?

Tags: t-test, chi-squared-test, group-differences, method-comparison

I need some help to figure out how to choose the appropriate statistical analysis, it's driving me crazy.

We are conducting a service evaluation, where we have two different groups who voted on their priorities for the service (11 priorities). Each person could vote on their top 3 priorities (voted for multiple priorities) which means that the counts are not independent.

I now have the following dataset:

| Priorities | Group 1 | Group 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 26 | 14 |
| 2 | 25 | 8 |
| 3 | 20 | 7 |
| etc | 16 | 9 |

Additionally, our groups have different sample sizes (twice as many people in our first group).The first group has a sample size of 55, and the second group of 30.

I had a voter turnout of about 50% in both groups, as around half of people in each group declined to vote. Although I don't need to extend the results to people who were not surveyed - I just want to uncover significant differences between the two groups of voters (55 in the first and 30 in the second).

I want to know which priority differs significantly between the groups; for example, I want to be able to say "People from our group 1 were more likely to vote for x priority than people from group 2".

Any idea which test could be used for this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you also have the individual level data ? If so then perhaps you can use a mixed effects model with random intercepts for the individuals.

Comment: You should probably mention how people have been selected to vote/participate in your survey, as it could affect the answers you may get (did all the people in the two groups vote? Only some of them? If so, why them and not others? etc.). Also, do you want to generalize the observed difference to people who have not been surveyed? Or are you interested only in the difference among the people you surveyed, and only them? If you can, giving a bit more context might be useful to get more relevant answers.

Comment: @RobertLong thank you for your help! I do have the individual level data (so with every priority as a binary outcome, with 1 = voted for this priority, 0 = did not vote for this priority), I am just confused as to how I would set this up in a model as I have the 11 different priorities (so if I look at individual level data, I have in theory 11 different outcomes?)

Comment: OK, thanks for confirming that. Please can you edit the question, and show the structure of the individual level dataset (just the first few rows should do it), and please answer the comment made by @J-J-J above.